# Is it possible to execute Server side code before executing client side code in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a Link button in `DataGrid` for to edit the grid data, I'm using `OnClientClick` event for loading a modal form and also i'm using `onSelectedIndexChanged` event function of the GRID for loading editing data to to controls. see the server side code below

```
    protected void GetSelectedData(Object src, EventArgs e)
{
    String Team_Id = GridView1.DataKeys[GridView1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
    using (MySqlConnection DbConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStr"]))
    {
        DbConnection.Close();
        string cmdText = "SELECT Team_Id,Team_code,Team_Name FROM Team_Details WHERE Team_Id=?Id";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, DbConnection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?Id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Team_Id);
        DbConnection.Open();
        MySqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (DR.Read())
        {
            this.txtTeamCode.Text = DR.GetValue(1).ToString();
            this.txtTeamName.Text = DR.GetValue(2).ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

see the Client side code for invoking the modal window,

```
        function EditDialog(){ 
        $('#newTeam').dialog("open");   
        alert(document.Team.txtTeamCode.value);          
        document.getElementById("cvCode").innerHTML = '';
        document.Team.txtTeamCode.focus();                   
    }
```

The problem is, while poping up the modal form, the fields (team code & team name) are getting blank. Please provide a solution to solve this issue.

Comment: you can use RegisterStartupScript at last of server code

Comment: Might want to rethink your post's title too, because server-side code _always_ executes first _on the server_ before the client-side code _on the client_.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an AJAX request to populate the modal pop-up's fields - call an object/service that would return the required data items and then modify the GUI accordingly.

Take a look at JQuery's [get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function. For usability it's probably best to do this asynchronously.

[Here's a decent tutorial](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1606-Ask-Ben-Dynamic-Form-Field-Population-With-jQuery.htm) that offers a possible implementation.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of httphandlers or as the prev user mentioned make ajax calls.
You can also make use of [Pagemethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page_methods.aspx) to call the server side code from javascript.